# Wix v4: Run custom action only on install

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix4

In wix 3 you could specify a condition inside the [custom element](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/custom/).

In wix 4 the same element does not seem to accept inner text anymore. If you try to set a condition the compiler throws a `The Custom element contains illegal inner text: 'NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE'` error. How would one go ahead and only run the custom action during the installation now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Condition` is an attribute on the `Custom` element: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/schema/wxs/custom/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking the `REMOVE` parameter inside the custom action itself to check whether it got called during a uninstall and then run the logic accordingly.

```cs
var isUninstall = session["REMOVE"] == "ALL";
```

The only problem with that solution is that this way I cant make sure that the custom action logic does not run on patches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pro Tip:  WiX's v3 to v4 code converter is really good.  Author what you know in v3 and then convert it v4 and diff the before and after to quickly learn new changes in v4.